# Group the elements of a set into disjoint subsets using iteration instead of recursion

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

I came across [Pascal Bourguignon's solutions](https://www.informatimago.com/develop/lisp/l99/) of the [99 Lisp problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2006s2/funcional/L-99_Ninety-Nine_Lisp_Problems.html) and was wondering if his recursive solution of problem 27 using a nested `mapcan`-`mapcar`-construct could also be written using nested loops.

His solution is definitely very elegant:

```
(defun group (set sizes)
  (cond
    ((endp sizes)
     (error "Not enough sizes given."))
    ((endp (rest sizes))
     (if (= (first sizes) (length set))
         (list (list set))
         (error "Cardinal mismatch |set| = ~A ; required ~A"
                (length set) (first sizes))))
    (t
     (mapcan (lambda (combi)
               (mapcar (lambda (group) (cons combi group))
                       (group (set-difference set combi) (rest sizes))))
            (combinations (first sizes) set)))))
```

The function `combinations` is defined [here](https://www.informatimago.com/develop/lisp/l99/p26.lisp) as:

```
(defun combinations (count list)
  (cond
    ((zerop count) '(())) ; one combination of zero element.
    ((endp list)   '())   ; no combination from no element.
    (t (nconc (mapcar (let ((item (first list)))
                      (lambda (combi) (cons item combi)))
                    (combinations (1- count) (rest list)))
            (combinations count (rest list))))))
```

I started with a simple approach:

```
(defun group-iter (set sizes)
  (loop :with size = (first sizes)
        :for subgroup :in (combination size set)
        :for remaining = (set-difference set subgroup)
        :collect (list subgroup remaining) :into result
        :finally (return result)))
```

which results in:

```
> (group-iter '(a b c d e f) '(2 2 2))
 (((A B) (F E D C)) ((A C) (F E D B)) ((A D) (F E C B)) ((A E) (F D C B))
  ((A F) (E D C B)) ((B C) (F E D A)) ((B D) (F E C A)) ((B E) (F D C A))
  ((B F) (E D C A)) ((C D) (F E B A)) ((C E) (F D B A)) ((C F) (E D B A))
  ((D E) (F C B A)) ((D F) (E C B A)) ((E F) (D C B A)))
```

But now I am totally failing to implement the nesting which takes care of the further processing of `remaining`. As far as I understood there is always a way to express a recursion with a iteration but how does it look like here?